# Block redirecting after clicking on the button inside Link React

Tags: java, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

What can I do so that clicking on the `<Button/>` inside `<Link>` component wont't redirect me to the site inside `to` and after clicking `<OtherStuff />` it will redirect me.

```
<Link to="">
 <OtherStuff />
 <Button />
</Link>
```

Comment: What if you just wrapped <OtherStuff /> component inside of the <Link />?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered incorrect to nest an interactive element inside other interactive elements, but if you want to link to work ***only when*** the `OtherStuff` component is clicked then you can stop the propagation of the `Button` component's click event so it isn't propagated up to the `Link` component.

Example `Button`:

```
const Button = () => {
  const clickHandler = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ... other click logic
  };

  return <button type="button onClick={clickHandler}>Text</button>;
};
```

...

```
<Link to="">
 <OtherStuff />
 <Button />
</Link>
```